# Segmentation fault description explanation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

When I got a segmentation fault like this:

> sending SIGSEGV to MyProcess for invalid read access from (epc == 00000000, ra == 1aca1ed8)

What means the `epc == 00000000`  and  `ra == 1aca1ed8`?

Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: it would be helpful to tag your os

Answer (score 3):

- `epc` is the `Exception Program Counter`, it should point to the address of
  the instruction that caused the exception.
- `ra` is the `Return Address` register, it should point to the address to return from the
  function call.